# highchart stock : graph disappear when containing weekend data point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Recently I met a very strange problem when using highchart stock(highstock.js). I load some data points which containing Saturday data point. When application runs, at first it looks like this:
[image: abnormal 1]

No graph appear, only the navigator and the time axis label. However, when I drag the navigator to the full size, the graph appear, but the x-axis time label disappear, it looks like this:
[image: abnormal 2]

I have built a plunker here: [graph disappear when met weekend data point link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8uRKHPzQVtUyJIjg1K8C?p=streamer)

some main configuration codes are as below:

```
    scrollbar : {
        barBackgroundColor : 'gray',
        barBorderRadius : 7,
        barBorderWidth : 0,
        buttonBackgroundColor : 'gray',
        buttonBorderWidth : 0,
        buttonArrowColor : 'yellow',
        buttonBorderRadius : 7,
        rifleColor : 'yellow',
        trackBackgroundColor : 'white',
        trackBorderWidth : 1,
        trackBorderColor : 'silver',
        trackBorderRadius : 7,
        // enabled: false,
        liveRedraw : false    
    },
    navigator : {
        xAxis : {
            labels : {
                formatter : function(e) {
                    console.log("value : " + this.value);
                    console.log("value :" + typeof this.value)
                    return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.value);
                }
            }
        },
        handles : {
            backgroundColor : '#808080'
        },
    //margin : -10
    },
    xAxis : {
        type : 'datetime',
        tickLength : 0
    },
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the true reason. It is not because the weekend data point, but because the data is not sorted in time ascending order.